# Symmetry of function and symmetry of level sets.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

:)  I've been thinking about the following:  if $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to [0,\infty)$ is an even and continuous function, then it's super level sets $S_t= \{x : f(x)\geq t\}$  are symmetric about the origin for every $t>0$.  This seems to be intuitively clear, but I worry that I am wrong. Any additional opinions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The property is true. Let $E_t = \{ f(x) \ge t \}$. We have to show that $E_t = -E_t$. Take an element $x \in E_t$. Then $f(x) = f(-x) \ge t$, so that $-x \in E_t$, and $x \in -E_t.$ This proves that $E_t \subseteq -E_t$. The other inclusion is similarly proven.